# setState always (I want to setState Status as success always if I go to the previous screen or go to the next screen)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

```js
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Status: '',
    };
  }
  Successful = () => {
    console.log('Status' + this.state.Status);
    if (this.state.Status === 'SUCCESS') {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('OScreen');
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>PAY</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}                                 
            onPress=this.setState({Status: 'SUCCESS'});>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text style={styles.pay}>Proceed</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
   }
```

Comment: The `this.setState({Status: 'SUCCESS'});` code in the `onPress` property is directly executed when the `render` method is executed. You should wrap the code in a function so that it is executed when the onPress event is fired: `onPress={() => this.setState({Status: 'SUCCESS'}) }`

Answer (score 0):

wrap the onpress with function

```
onPress={() => { alert('doing something') } }
```

```js
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Status: '',
    };
  }
  

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>PAY</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}                                 
            onPress={()=>{
                this.setState({Status: 'SUCCESS'});
                this.props.navigation.navigate('OScreen');
            }}>
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text style={styles.pay}>Proceed</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
   }
```